# Using Ramda map helper in pointfree way

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

How can I change this code:

```
 map(user => assoc('isAdult', isAdult(user), user)
```

to function pointfree (using Ramda). I was thinking how to do it with [useWith](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith), but can't find working implementation.

Any ideas?

```
import { pipe, prop, gte, __, map, assoc, sortWith, descend } from 'ramda'

const isAdult = pipe(
  prop('age'),
  gte(__, 18)
)

const func = pipe(
  map(user => assoc('isAdult', isAdult(user), user)),
  sortWith([
    descend(prop('isAdult')),
    descend(prop('age')),
  ])
)

export default func
```

**EDIT** (more info):

I want to create a function that returns array of objects extended by the `isAdult` key. If the user is more than 18 years old, we set the flag to `true`.

In addition, the function should return users sorted by the flag `isAdult` and then sorted by the key `age`.

Sample data:

```
const data1 = [
  {
    name: 'Cassidy David',
    email: 'sit@Nullaeuneque.co.uk',
    id: 'FC92BF1E-A6FD-E5C1-88AB-183BD1BC59C5',
    position: 1,
    age: 53,
    created_at: '2017-04-07'
  },
  {
    name: 'Gwendolyn Edwards',
    email: 'ut.mi.Duis@elementumsemvitae.net',
    id: '00000001-ED9D-3A88-0D3C-07A148FD43ED',
    position: 2,
    age: 10,
    created_at: '2016-05-21'
  },
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more what is the result that you want to achieve, with an example or something? It is not clear from the code what you expect as output

Comment: @MarioF sure, I've just updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's debatable whether trying to make this point-free is useful.

This is quite readable as is:

```
map(user => assoc('isAdult', isAdult(user), user)),
```

Point-free is a great technique that can sometimes enhance readability.  But if it doesn't, I wouldn't bother with it.

That said, if you do want to try point-free, [`chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) is probably most helpful.  Note how chain works for functions: `chain(f, g)(x) //=> f(g(x), x)`.

So you can write your relevant part as

```
map(chain(assoc('isAdult'), isAdult))
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data1%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Cassidy%20David%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20%27sit%40Nullaeuneque.co.uk%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%27FC92BF1E-A6FD-E5C1-88AB-183BD1BC59C5%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20position%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%2053%2C%0A%20%20%20%20created_at%3A%20%272017-04-07%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Gwendolyn%20Edwards%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20%27ut.mi.Duis%40elementumsemvitae.net%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%2700000001-ED9D-3A88-0D3C-07A148FD43ED%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20position%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20created_at%3A%20%272016-05-21%27%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20isAdult%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20prop%28%27age%27%29%2C%0A%20%20gte%28__%2C%2018%29%0A%29%0A%0Amap%28chain%28assoc%28%27isAdult%27%29%2C%20isAdult%29%29%28data1%29)**.

Comment: cool solution! The docs make it quite hard to figure out that `chain` does just his, imo

Comment: The second example is supposed to make it clear.  But if not, thinking of functions as chains, in the current signature of `Chain m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`, we can think of functions from `r` to something as our Chains, and replace all `m x` with `(r -> x)` giving `(a -> (r -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)`, and associativity will transform that to `(a -> r -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)`.  So with `x :: r` and `g :: x -> a` we get `f :: a -> r -> b`, and `chain` can only be satisfied with `chain(f, g) = x -> f(g(x), x).`

Comment: Thank you very much @ScottSauyet !

Comment: @ScottSauyet This is a nice application of the reader monad. Is there a particular reason why you switched the arguments for `chain`? Usually I like to write `chain(unaryF) (x => chain(unaryF) (y => of(...))`.

Comment: @ftor: Not quite sure what you were asking about.  Perhaps [Ramda issue #1936](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1936) and [#1937](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1937) are relevant.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, thanks! You might want to consider state/writer monads for Ramda as well. Leaving out all the type machinery in Haskell, `bind` is just a (very) special form of function composition for these monads. Introducing new monads would require to rename `chain` of course, because Ramda doesn't have a mechanism for overloaded functions, right?

Comment: @ftor: Ramda does not really supply types.  It doesn't even supply `Maybe` or `Either`.  It is focused on functions working with existing types.  But it interoperates with many FantasyLand types.  For instance, `map` will delegate to a FL functor, if the type is not one supplied by Ramda's own code (Array, Object, or Function in that case.)  `chain` is similar.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ya, I know that. There are monads that are associated with algebraic data types (e.g. List, Maybe, etc.) and others that are associated with function types. Ramda's chain (aka Reader) is one of the latter. State/Writer likewise. All you need are functions and with State you can share state across function calls and with Writer you can compose functions that return an additional value.

Answer (score 3):

Alright I got a solution, although it is pretty debatable whether this is an improvement in clarity over what you have already:

```
const newFields = map(pipe(isAdult, objOf('isAdult')))(data1)
zipWith(merge, data1, newFields)
```

So I'm doing one extra pass where I generate a list with objects that just have the new key and merge them together, and then I combine the lists.

I could not get a solution where you do one pass without avoiding an arrow function like the one you did.

EDIT: Scott Sauyet's solution addresses the problem quite well actually